# Retrieving list values within custom task form

Tags: list, custom-form

I've created a custom list (PBE) and attached a workflow which creates a task. When I edit the task, I am in my custom task form (.aspx)

I want to check a value in a field in my orginal custom list (pbe). The url passed to the custom task form has several parameters, but I think list = task list. 
In ID parameter I can see the original list guid.

Is it possible to retrieve the orginal PBE data through the task list or do I need to edit the url ID field, saying this I dont have a reference to the item itself ?

I'm coding in c# and using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve item from workflow properties and set IDs of PBE item and list to extended properties of task

```
taskProperties.ExtendedProperties["ItemId"] = item.ID;
taskProperties.ExtendedProperties["ItemListId"] = item.ParentList.ID;
```

Then you can retrieve these values in your custom task form like this

```
Hashtable extendedProperties = SPWorkflowTask.GetExtendedPropertiesAsHashtable(task);
var listId = extendedProperties["ItemListId"];
var itemId = extendedProperties["ItemId"];
```

You can access to the field like this

```
var list = web.Lists[listId];
var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
var fieldValue = item[fieldId];
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks for this information, In my Custom Task Form I now have the two variables. listId and itemId. How Can I grab a field in the list with a certain ID ?

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want to get field, not a value of field, you can use list.Fields[fieldId] method.

Comment: HI

I accessed the fields like this, though it works its more complex, have I done it the long way ?

this._sharePointListAttachedTo1 = this._myTeamSite.Lists[new Guid(listId)];

this._listItemObject1 = this._sharePointListAttachedTo1.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(itemId));

Label5.Text = Convert.ToString(_listItemObject1["AT pbe entry user"]);

Comment: Wheres a good place to learn about these classes and methods ? Not too keen on the msdn site..

Comment: I know only one site for this. it is a Google.com ;)